# load multiple flv videos using FileReferenceList class

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder

following is my code for loading one video using FileReference class and it works fine

```
[Event(name="complete",type="flash.events.Event")]  
[Event(name="status",type="flash.events.StatusEvent")]  
public class LocalFileLoader extends EventDispatcher  
{  
    public function LocalFileLoader()  
    {}      
    private var file:FileReference;// = FileReference(event.target);  
    private var list:FileReferenceList; 
    public var p2pSharedObject:P2PSharedObject = new P2PSharedObject();  
    public function browseFileSystem():void {  
        file = new FileReference();  
        list = new FileReferenceList();  
        list.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);  
        list.browse();  
    }  
    protected function selectHandler(event:Event):void {  
        for each ( file in list.fileList ){  
            file.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);    
            file.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);  
            file.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);         
            file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);  
            writeText(file.name+" | "+file.size);  
            file.load();      
        }   
    }   
    protected function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {  
        writeText("securityError: " + event);  
    }  
    protected function completeHandler(event:Event):void {  
        writeText("completeHandler");  
        p2pSharedObject = new P2PSharedObject();  
        p2pSharedObject.size = file.size;  
        p2pSharedObject.packetLength = Math.floor(file.size/32000)+1;  
        p2pSharedObject.data = file.data;  
        p2pSharedObject.chunks = new Object();  
        var desc:Object = new Object();  
        desc.totalChunks = p2pSharedObject.packetLength+1;  
        desc.name = file.name;  
        p2pSharedObject.chunks[0] = desc;  
        for(var i:int = 1;i<p2pSharedObject.packetLength;i++){  
            p2pSharedObject.chunks[i] = new ByteArray();  
            p2pSharedObject.data.readBytes(p2pSharedObject.chunks[i],0,32000);  
        }  
        // +1 last packet  
        p2pSharedObject.chunks[p2pSharedObject.packetLength] = new ByteArray();  
        p2pSharedObject.data.readBytes(p2pSharedObject.chunks[i],0,p2pSharedObject.data.bytesAvailable);  
        p2pSharedObject.packetLength+=1;  
        writeText("----- p2pSharedObject -----");  
        writeText("packetLenght: "+(p2pSharedObject.packetLength));  
        dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));  
    }  
    protected function writeText(str:String):void{  
        var e:StatusEvent = new StatusEvent(StatusEvent.STATUS,false,false,"status",str);  
        dispatchEvent(e);  
    }  
}
```

the sender.mxml code is following which plays the video on the stage

```
private function init() : void {  
    fileLoader = new LocalFileLoader();  
    fileLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileLoaded);  
    fileShare = new P2PFileShare();  
    fileShare.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS,
            function(event:StatusEvent):void {  
                writeText(event.level);  
            });    
    fileShare.connect();  
}    

private function fileLoaded ( event:Event ) : void {  
    writeText("fileLoaded");  
    if (fileShare.connected) {  
        fileShare.p2pSharedObject = fileLoader.p2pSharedObject;  
        fileShare.p2pSharedObject.lastIndexBegin = 0;  
        fileShare.p2pSharedObject.lastIndexEnd = fileShare.p2pSharedObject.packetLength-1;  
        fileShare.updateHaveObjects();  
    }  
    setupVideo();  
    // PLAY  
    ns.play(null);  

    ns.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN);               
    ns.appendBytes(fileLoader.p2pSharedObject.data);  
    video.attachNetStream(ns);  
}  

private function setupVideo():void{  
    var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();  
    nc.connect(null);  
    ns = new NetStream(nc);  
    ns.client = this;  
    ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, 
            function(event:NetStatusEvent):void{  
                writeText("stream: "+event.info.code);  
            });  
    video = new Video();  
    videoComp = new UIComponent();  
    videoComp.addChild(video);  
    this.addElement(videoComp);  
}
```

then after this, the file.name and file.size goes to mxml page and the video is displayed on stage with name and file size 
but the samething i want to do with FileReferenceList class, i am solving this problem from last 2 weeks but cant ,,, plz guide me ,,, i google so many times but no specific answer
Regards
Ammad Khan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [fileList property](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/FileReferenceList.html#fileList) of the FileReferenceList class to access the files that where selected.  Then load() each FileReference in the list separately:

```
private var list:FileReferenceList;

public function browseFileSystem():void {

    list = new FileReferenceList();  
    list.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);  
    list.browse();  
} 

protected function selectHandler(event:Event):void {  

    for each ( var file:FileReference in list.fileList) {
        file.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);  
        file.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);  
        file.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);  
        file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);  
        writeText(file.name+" | "+file.size);           
        file.load(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply "weltraumpirat" , the above code helped me alot ,, now i  can load multiple videos, and also the video is played on the stage , but now i am facing that only one video is playing ,,, i actually want that is user select 2 flv videos , these videos should be loaded and also they must play at stage one after another ,, any suggestion on it ? would be highly appreciated ,, once again many thanks for reply .....

Comment: Hm, it depends.  I've never used FileReference to load videos from the local disk.  Do you use any video components to play those?  Do they play automatically?  If you tell me more, maybe I can help.

Comment: yes, i use the video object to play the videos. actually before the file.loaded(), an event listener calls which use the funtion completeHandler, in which i use file.name and file.size to divide it into 128 kb packets( all this done in LocalFileLoader.as class ) then Sender.mxml makes an instance of LocalFileLoader class and on complete event listener, it calls the setupVideo function which plays the video on stage.

Comment: Then it shouldn't be too hard: Load only the first movie (`fileList[0].load()` after the for each loop instead of `file.load()` within the loop).  Keep a counter variable! I suspect you use `attachNetStream` to add the video to your Video object - add an event listener to `NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS` and react to NetStream.Play.Stop http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html#info .  Then increase your counter value and load the next item from the fileList.

Comment: thanks for giving me time, i successfully implement the logic u mentioned above, but how code i react NetStrean.Play.Stop event, i use the following NetStatusEvent.Net_Status event listener, infact i following is the complete function of setting up video

Comment: ammad, please don't post so much code into comments - it's unreadable and doesn't help others.  Rather make this a new question, since it strays quite a bit from the original topic.

Comment: well i have tried 2nd logic to but it works same as the previous one, i am trying to sort out it , also tried different variations but same result ,, it loads both the movies, first movie plays on stage but second one remain unplayed ,,, any furthur suggestions ?

Comment: Are you sure you took the `file.load()` out of the loop?  If you only tell one FileReference to load, then only one movie should be loaded!

Comment: Hm yes, i do took it out of the loop, and instead of file.load() i am using list.fileList[0].load()( out of the loop) to load the movies,it loads the movie but first one, i also tried list.fileList[1].load() but it too loads the first one, i also used list.fileList[0].load() inside the loop and got same result.

Comment: Ah, okay.  So only the first one plays, but the second one never starts...  Have you traced the NetStatus events on the first video?  Are they ever fired?

Comment: yes i am tracing the NetStatus events and it also fired i think because when the video ends, a text box shows me that NetStream.Buffer.Empty, then i wait for the second video but it never plays.

Comment: It should say NetStream.Play.Start and NetStream.Play.Stop at some point.  Can you verify these?

Comment: Hm, well when video loads the it say NetStream.Buffer.Full and at the end it show NetStream.Buffer.Empty, but it doesnot fire NetStream.Play.Stop or NetStream.Play.Start.

Comment: Hm, perhaps you'll have to settle for the NetStream.Buffer.Empty.  Have you tried that?

Comment: i thinks so , i have tried it too, now istead of NetStream.Buffer.Empty it shows NetStream.Play.Start

Comment: I tried all sort of NetStatus events, but the second file doesnot plays at stage , one more thing i have done is to replace list.fileList[0] with list.fileList[counter] but it does not play even firt flv, i set counter variable innitally equal to 0 and it increment by one in the loop, any suggestion in this regard?

Comment: If you set the counter to 0 before the loop and then increment it, it will be equal to list.fileList.length after the loop is done.  That means, list.fileList[counter] would throw an error, since the array's last entry is at list.fileList.length-1.

Comment: If the event triggers correctly, there might be something wrong about another part of the program.  Perhaps the load() instruction in the event handler is not set up right?

Comment: Yes, you are right,i have set the counter=0 before the loop but if we loop at the sequential order of the loop the counter increment it self at the end of the loop , moreover i have checked the whole program thoroughly and i didnot find any misplacement

Comment: Well, something has to be wrong, otherwise it would work as expected ;)  Seems there is no other way than to trace your way through.

Comment: oh, one more thing, when i call to completeHandler it take list.fileList[counter].data and put it in a ByteArray where it divides the file into 32 kb packets for sending to receiver. the thing i notice here is counter variable because counter is set in the selectHandler function and i am using it also in completeHandler function, should i place a loop in the completeHandler too ?

Comment: The completeHandler for loading? You can just use `FileReference (event.target).data`, no need to persist the counter, and no need to access the list again.  You should check that method closely, it is probably where your error is located.

Comment: well i even change the whole method but it still giving me the same result, the final selected file by user is loaded but the other still did not load, any other idea why it does not load the first 4 flvs?

Comment: Edit your code in the question to reflect all the changes you have made so far - I kind of lost track ;)

Comment: Hm i have attach all the file with important code, please go through it you will definitely understand it,, kindly reply me soon..

Comment: The code seems fine, as far as I can tell.  How about the part where you actually play the video?  It doesn't seem to be in there.

Comment: i have uploaded the code for video displaying, it is beneath the sender.mxml, this code just plays NetStream in video object, please have a kind look over it..

Comment: I will. And it's the second time I formatted your code for you - please always use the {} or indent everything by 4 spaces.

Comment: From what I can tell, it is probably a side effect: All your objects are member variables (which means that every time you call `ns = new NetStream()`, for instance, you lose the reference to the "last" NetStream you created).  This will most certainly lead to problems, because you never know in which sequence the movies are done loading, or how fast this will be done - you might well be attaching four files to the same NetStream, or four NetStreams to the same Video.  You need only one NetConnection, but for all other objects I would recommend keeping arrays instead of a single object.

Comment: sorry for wrong formatted code, well so i need to declare all objects as object arrays it means ?

Comment: When you have multiple items you want to track, and they all need to be available as members - yes.

Comment: i did not understood your point can you please make it clear , because i have done all the work you mentioned, firstly inject file.name into desc object now i am inserting this file.name into desc array and iterate this array one by one but still i got the final video load, i think timer might can solve this problem , what do you say ?

Comment: I don't know your current code.  Update your question, please.